# mysql load xml statement produces 0 records

Tags: mysql, xml

I'm using the following statement in a mySQL workbench query:

```
LOAD XML INFILE 'ProductFile.xml' INTO TABLE myDB.products 
ROWS IDENTIFIED BY '<product>';
```

which produces the following log:

> 19:15:52  LOAD XML INFILE 'ProductFile.xml' INTO TABLE myDB.products ROWS IDENTIFIED BY ''   0 row(s) affected Records: 0  Deleted: 0  Skipped: 0  Warnings: 0   0.000 sec

ProductFile.xml contains data in the following format:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<products>
  <product>
    <name>Thing 1</name>
    <productUrl>http://www.productsite.com/linkofsomesorttothing1</productUrl>
    <ProductId>1234567890</ProductId>
  </product>
  <product>
    <name>Thing 2</name>
    <productUrl>http://www.productsite.com/linkofsomesorttothing2</productUrl>
    <ProductId>1234567891</ProductId>
  </product>
</products>
```

myDB.products is as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `myDB`.`Products` (
  `ProductId` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `name` VARCHAR(70) NOT NULL,
  `productUrl` TEXT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (`ProductId`),
   UNIQUE INDEX `ProductId_UNIQUE` (`ProductId` ASC)
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB COMMENT='\n';
```

Can anyone tell me why it's producing no output?

Comment: Update: it seems to be a problem with the actual data I have between the start and end tags (the data above is example data that I substituted for the actual data). I'll post an update once I've isolated the actual data that's causing the problem. It's a bit odd because there's nothing there that looks like html tags, so it beats me why the parser gets confused ...

Comment: I found one problem, which seems to stem from the character set. I think I need to specify the character set that corresponds to ISO-8859-1 on the LOAD statement ... latin1?

Comment: The problem indeed came from the character set. I needed to specify the character set that corresponds to ISO-8859-1 on the LOAD statement i.e. CHARACTER SET latin1. Now it works!

Answer (score 0):

I can't reproduce the problem.

**File**: `/path/to/file/ProductFile.xml`

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<products>
  <product>
    <name>Thing 1</name>
    <productUrl>http://www.productsite.com/linkofsomesorttothing1</productUrl>
    <ProductId>1234567890</ProductId>
  </product>
  <product>
    <name>Thing 2</name>
    <productUrl>http://www.productsite.com/linkofsomesorttothing2</productUrl>
    <ProductId>1234567891</ProductId>
  </product>
</products>
```

**MySQL Command-Line**:

```sql
mysql> DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `Products`;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Products` (
    ->   `ProductId` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    ->   `name` VARCHAR(70) NOT NULL,
    ->   `productUrl` TEXT,
    ->   PRIMARY KEY (`ProductId`),
    ->   UNIQUE KEY `ProductId_UNIQUE` (`ProductId`)
    -> ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 COMMENT='\n';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)

mysql> LOAD XML INFILE '/path/to/file/ProductFile.xml'
    ->   INTO TABLE `Products`
    ->   ROWS IDENTIFIED BY '<product>';
Query OK, 2 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Records: 2  Deleted: 0  Skipped: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> SELECT
    ->   `ProductId`,
    ->   `name`,
    ->   `productUrl`
    -> FROM
    ->   `Products`;
+------------+---------+---------------------------------------------------+
| ProductId  | name    | productUrl                                        |
+------------+---------+---------------------------------------------------+
| 1234567890 | Thing 1 | http://www.productsite.com/linkofsomesorttothing1 |
| 1234567891 | Thing 2 | http://www.productsite.com/linkofsomesorttothing2 |
+------------+---------+---------------------------------------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Thanks for trying @wchiquito. There must be something wrong with the way I've got my sql server configured, but I've no idea what.

Answer (score 0):

The problem came from the character set. I needed to specify the character set that corresponds to ISO-8859-1 on the LOAD statement i.e. CHARACTER SET latin1. Now it works!